# Java replacing / removing / writing text in a certain spot in a txt file

Tags: java

So they the file I wanna edit is this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<UserSettingsXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AuthType>Google</AuthType> <!-- Google/Ptc -->
  <DefaultLatitude>425</DefaultLatitude> 
  <DefaultLongitude>5555</DefaultLongitude>
```

The places I wanna edit, and remove text from is

```
  <DefaultLatitude>425</DefaultLatitude> 
  <DefaultLongitude>5555</DefaultLongitude>
```

I've googled a bit but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Take some time to look at some XML parsing in Java tutorial. Check [XML Parsing for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm) , and another one: [XML and Java - Parsing XML using Java Tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)

Comment: Did you ever tried something besides googling? Like, write some `Java` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alter an XML file you should be using something like [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html).

That's easier and safer to do than just altering the text in the file.

---

Reading the xml-file into a DOM-`Document` is quite easy:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = db.parse(new File(filename));
```

After that you'll have to find the right spot in the XML-Document and alter it:

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList found = root.getElementsByTagName("DefaultLatitude");
Node element = found.item(0);
String textContent = element.getTextContent();  // contains 425 now
element.setTextContent("987");                  // set new text
```

After that you'll have to write out the changed document to a file:

```
TransformerFactory tranformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tranformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outputFile));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

---

Please note that this is just an example on how to read, alter and save a XML-File. To properly work with DOM you'll have to read some tutorials!

Comment: You'll still have to save the resulting document. I'll edit my post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to edit is in xml format. The best way to do what you want is to:
1. parse the file in xml
2. manipulate the xml
3. build the file again

A good page where to learn how to convert from text to xml is this:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

The rest is easier. I hope this helps.